# matrix differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

Given a matrix $X(t)=e^{tA}$, we know that $X(t)$ is the solution of the following matrix differential equation:
$$ \frac{dX(t)}{dt} =X(t) \cdot A .$$

Now could anyone help to construct a matrix differential equation in terms of $Y(t)$, such that $Y(t)=e^{tA} \cdot e^{tB}$ is its solution?

(NOTE: the matrices $A$ and $B$ do not commute, meaning that $e^{A+B} \neq e^A \cdot e^B.$ )

Comment: What did you try? Did you compute $Y'(t)$?

Comment: I want to construct a matrix differential equation such that its solution is $Y(t) = e^{tA} \cdot e^{tB}$.

Comment: The IMO easiest way to do so is computing $Y'(t)$ (as you KNOW the solution).

Comment: @JohnSmith: martini is right. Take the derivative and you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dt} Y 
&=& \left(\frac{d}{dt} e^{t A}\right) e^{t B} +  e^{t A} \left(\frac{d}{dt}e^{t B}\right) \\
&=& A e^{t A} e^{t B} + e^{t A}e^{t B} B \\
&=& A Y + Y B.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Since $A$ commutes with itself, it also commutes with $e^{t A}$, so 
$\frac{d}{dt} e^{t A} = A e^{t A} = e^{t A}A$.
If you are unfamiliar with matrix calculus, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Matrix-by-scalar) is not a bad place to start.

Comment: Is $\frac{d}{dt} e^{tA} = A e^{tA}$ or $\frac{d}{dt} e^{tA} = e^{tA} A $ ?

Comment: @JohnSmith: Notice that $A$ commutes with itself, so they are the same thing.

Comment: @JohnSmith oenamen's argument become obvious, when you write down the Taylor series for $e^{tA}$.

Comment: Yeah, I see. Thanks! The key point is that $e^{A}$ and $A$ are commutative.